# Passing by assignment: Python

Tags: python, pass-by-reference, variable-assignment

I wanted to make sense of the following code variations:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a
b.append(4)
b = ['a', 'b']
print(a, b)
```

What I understood was that variable `a` refers to an object that contains the list `[1,2,3]` in some place in memory, and `b` now is referring to the same object that `a` is referring to, and via that link we're technically appending in a not b.

Output: `[1, 2, 3, 4] ['a', 'b']`

I updated the code a bit:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ['a', 'b']
b = a
b.append(4)
print(a, b)
```

My understanding: b is now referring to two objects, the first list  `['a','b']` and the second list (that `a` is initially referring to) `[1,2,3]` via the third line `b = a`.

Output: `[1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 2, 3, 4]`

Last Code variation:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ['a', 'b']
b = a
b.append(4)
a.append(10)
print(a, b)
```

based on my understanding so far, I though that the link on line 3 `b = a` was giving only `b` the ability to reference multiple objects (it's own and `a`'s) and `a` should've only be referencing one object `[1,2,3]`, so the expected output should be: `[1,2,3,4,10] [1,2,3,4]`

Actual Output: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 10] [1, 2, 3, 4, 10]`

So is this assignment on line 3 `b = a` is like a bi-directional link? where also a reference is created by `a` to `b`'s object?

I hope someone can clear this confusion for me and correct me on my thoughts if I was wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: the variable a and the variable b refer to the same list . if you change one of them, the other also recieves these changes. If you want to copy a list, use new_list = list.copy() This may also help: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/copy

Comment: Why do you make this so complicated? After `b = a`, `a` and `b` are the same object, that's all there is to it.

Comment: @Creepsy Thanks Bud! That was a really useful link!

Comment: "we're technically appending in a not b." no. Variables refer to objects. Both variables are referring to the same object and you append *to that object*. You don't append to a variable. "My understanding: b is now referring to two objects" Well, *not at the same time*. It referred to one object at the beginning, and refers to another later. Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Note, this has nothing to do with "passing by assignment", which refers to an *evaluation strategy*, which has to do with how and when function arguments are evaluated, not simple assignment like this.

Comment: "based on my understanding so far, I though that the link on line 3 b = a was giving only b the ability to reference multiple objects (it's own and a's) and a " no. **variables can only ever refer to one object at a time**. I think this is what is confusing you.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I seriously can't thank you enough on the article you mentioned! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't think of the objects like pointers, I think that is the source of your confusion. It is not that "b points to a" or "a points to b", it has to do with *binding* to an object. I think looking at `id` will be useful

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> id(a)
1833964774216
>>> b = a
>>> id(b)
1833964774216
```

In this case both `a` and `b` are bound to that list. So any mutation to list `1833964774216` will be reflected in both objects. But I can re-assign (or re-bind) to a completely different object

```
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> id(b)
1833965089992
>>> b
[4, 5, 6]
```

This has no effect whatsoever on `a` because it is still bound to the original list

```
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> id(a)
1833964774216
```

Answer (score 9):

> My understanding: b is now referring to two objects, . . .

That is not correct. A name cannot be associated with multiple objects within a given scope at the same time.

`b = a` associates `b` with the object that `a` is associated with. After that line has executed, nothing will be referencing `['a', 'b']`, and that list should be eligible for garbage collection because it can no longer be used.

Answer (score 1):

let’s understand the difference between names and objects. In your case, a and b are names, and the list "[1,2,3]" assigned to a and b is the object. Initially a = [1,2,3] and after a is assigned to b i.e. b=a, in this case both a and b are bound to the same list object. This means that you can change that list object’s value by using either of the names a or b.

This can be overcome by copying the list assigned to a to b as,

b = a.copy()

which will create a copy of same object assigned to b